# How to sort output while looping through dictionary by member variable?

Tags: python, sorting

how to sort dictiony by member variable

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, _name, _index, _price):
        self.name = _name
        self.index = _index
        self.price = _price
```

I want to show item information ordered by index or price.

```
DicItems = {}
DicItems["Candy"] = Item("Candy", 1, 100)
DicItems["IceCream"] = Item("IceCream", 2, 500)
DicItems["Snack"] = Item("Snack", 3, 300)
```

print items list order by index
->result

```
Candy     1 100
IceCream  2 500
Snack     3 300
```

print items list order by price
->result

```
Candy       1 100
Snack       3 300
IceCream    2 500
```

Answer (score 1):

**Prep Code:**

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, _name, _index, _price):
        self.name = _name
        self.index = _index
        self.price = _price
    def items(self):
        return self.name, self.index, self.price

d = {}
d["Candy"] = Item("Candy", 1, 100)
d["IceCream"] = Item("IceCream", 2, 500)
d["Snack"] = Item("Snack", 3, 300)
```

**Sorting Code:**

```
print [item.items() for item in sorted(d.values(), key = lambda x:x.index)]
print [item.items() for item in sorted(d.values(), key = lambda x:x.price)]
```

**Output**

```
[('Candy', 1, 100), ('IceCream', 2, 500), ('Snack', 3, 300)]
[('Candy', 1, 100), ('Snack', 3, 300), ('IceCream', 2, 500)]
```

Or we can generalize it with [attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) like this

```
from operator import attrgetter
def sorter(d, key):
    return [item.items() for item in sorted(d.values(), key = attrgetter(key))]

print sorter(d, "index")
print sorter(d, "name")
print sorter(d, "price")
```

**Output**

```
[('Candy', 1, 100), ('IceCream', 2, 500), ('Snack', 3, 300)]
[('Candy', 1, 100), ('IceCream', 2, 500), ('Snack', 3, 300)]
[('Candy', 1, 100), ('Snack', 3, 300), ('IceCream', 2, 500)]
```

Comment: Why not just `[item[1].items() for item in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].index)]`? Doing tons of lookups on the `dict` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Lattyware Changed it. We don't even need `items()`, I have used `values()` :)

Comment: Indeed, that looks good. +1.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks :) I generalized with `attrgetter` :)

Comment: `lambda x: getter(x))` kind of defies the point there - `getter` will do the same thing.

Comment: @Lattyware Is it? It doesn't sort for me, if I simply use `getter`.

Comment: @Lattyware Okay. I got what you are saying. Updated my answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python do not have any order.

For what you want, it can be achieved by doing following:

```
from operator import  attrgetter
name_getter = attrgetter('name')
index_getter = attrgetter('index')
price_getter = attrgetter('price')

sorted_by_index = sorted(DicItems, key=index_getter)
sorted_by_name = sorted(DicItems, key=name_getter)
sorted_by_price = sorted(DicItems, key=price_getter)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Yes, that was my lack of patience. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

more difficult, but more universally

```
from operator import attrgetter

class DictItems(dict):

     def sortByPrice():
         return sorted(self.values(), key=attrgetter('price'))

     def sortByIndex():
         return sorted(self.values(), key=attrgetter('index'))

d = DictItems()
d["Candy"] = Item("Candy", 1, 100)
d["IceCream"] = Item("IceCream", 2, 500)
d["Snack"] = Item("Snack", 3, 300)

d.sortByPrice()
d.sortByIndex()
```

Comment: maybe valuesSortedByPrice and valuesSortedByIndex would be better names, making it clearer that you are returning a new list of sorted values